# How to capitalize title tooltip in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pug

How do I capitalize only the first letter of the title tooltip (from a `span`)? I tried using CSS `text-transform: capitalize;`, but it didn't work.

```html
<template lang="pug">
    .cell-audience-status-dot(:class="{'overflow-initial': type === 'actions'}")
        .cell-content.audiences(v-if="data !== 'never_activated'")
            .icon-wrapper(:class="{ active : activeMenu === 'activeSegments' && openedSegments.includes(fullData.id) }")
                span.icon(:title="data" :class="getStatusColor") &#9679;
</template>

<script>
import { get } from 'vuex-pathify'

export default {
    name: 'cellStatus',
    props: ['data', 'type', 'fullData'],
    computed: {
        openedSegments: get('activeSegments/openedSegments'),
        activeMenu: get('menu/activeMenu'),
        getStatusColor() {
            const { data } = this
            if (data === 'active') return 'green'
            else if (data === 'inactive') return 'red'
            else if (data === 'paused') return 'orange'
            return ''
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) that returns the capitalized form of `data`:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    title() {
      return this.data?.length && this.data[0].toUpperCase() + this.data.slice(1)
    }
  }
}
```

And instead of `data`, bind the computed prop to the `span`'s `title` attribute:

```
span.icon(:title="title" :class="getStatusColor") &#9679;
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-capitalize-tooltip?file=src/App.vue)

Answer (score 1):

to capitalize only first letter of a text you can use the css selector `:first-letter` and `text-transform: uppercase;`

```css
 .title:first-letter {
     text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

```html
<div class="title">my text</div>
```